# DBPedia missing some English abstracts and comments

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm aware that DBpedia had a new release last week. It appears as if that release is missing some English abstract and comment fields.

For example, last week I was able to get the abstract for George Washington, now there are eight abstracts but none are in English.

sparql query:

```
  SELECT ?abstract
  WHERE { 
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/George_Washington> dbo:abstract ?abstract .
    FILTER langMatches( lang(?abstract), "en" )
  }
```

[sparql results](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3Fabstract%0D%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FGeorge_Washington%3E%20dbo%3Aabstract%20%3Fabstract%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20langMatches%28%20lang%28%3Fabstract%29%2C%20%22en%22%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)

Perhaps that data moved somewhere else? Any ideas on how to get that data now?

Comment: That's an issue in the DBpedia dataset which was extracted for the new release. You should ask or raise an issue on their Github page

Comment: I opened an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/dbpedia/extraction-framework/issues/486

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstracts for the most affected languages have been re-extracted, hot-fixed and replaced on the DBpedia SPARQL endpoint.

https://sourceforge.net/p/dbpedia/mailman/message/35490684/

Answer (score 1):

Short term, you might try the [LOD Cloud Cache](http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=PREFIX%20%20dbo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fabstract%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FGeorge_Washington%3E%20dbo%3Aabstract%20%3Fabstract%20.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20langMatches%28%20lang%28%3Fabstract%29%2C%20%22en%22%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) (also provided by my employer, [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), long-term sponsor of the [public DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql)) where I've just confirmed you'll currently find [the abstract you're looking for](http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX%20%20dbo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fabstract%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FGeorge_Washington%3E%20dbo%3Aabstract%20%3Fabstract%20.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20langMatches%28%20lang%28%3Fabstract%29%2C%20%22en%22%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on).

Longer term, there are [multiple GitHub projects/pages for DBpedia](https://github.com/dbpedia).  I suggest instead, [dbpedia-discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/dbpedia/mailman/dbpedia-discussion/), [@DBpedia](https://twitter.com/DBpedia), and/or [@OpenLink](https://twitter.com/OpenLink).

Answer (score 0):

Missing abstracts and comments have been restored with data from the 2015-10 dataset by OpenLink. See https://github.com/dbpedia/extraction-framework/issues/486#issuecomment-255142970